# gnustep runloop

Tags: nsrunloop, gnustep

Does anyone tell is GNUstep NSRunLoop extension functions:

- (void) addEvent: (void*)data
       type: (RunLoopEventType)type
    watcher: (id)watcher
    forMode: (NSString*)mode;

this method is work?, and how to setup the argument data?  I set a pipe to read file description, but it seems not work fine. Really hard to figure out the question, can anyone help me?

Comment: NSPipe instead of the file descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

This method works. Please show more of your code.

eg. for reading,
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addEvent: (void*)anFd
                      type: ET_RDESC
                   watcher: anObj // must implement receivedEvent:type:extra:forMode:
                   forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; // rtfm

Comment: thanks for your reply! and i code like your code , my design is:   I used pipe to post the information to the the other thread.I pipe_write a message, i want  the other thread could  listen to the pipe read, so i can handle the message on the thread. so  i set  addEvent: pipe_read, but it cant be work, i don't know the reason.should i do some magic thing to make the addEvent: function work?

Comment: There is no magic, addEvent:.. just adds the file descriptor to the system poll. I'm still not sure what you are trying to do here. Did you use NSThread? ie.-detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject: ? Or use distributed Object or perform selector on main thread? May be you can show more code or a minimal test case so I can get a clearer picture on what you are doing, how you actually run the loop, how you manage the loops between threads, even how you create the thread et al. You can also show the code to the GNUstep mailing list. They are very responsive.